# Android How to detect area touch in image in one image

Tags: android, image, touch, detection

this example image for split area.

http://postimg.org/image/j35tjjk57/

i want to detect when user touch number in image.

how to programming.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Path for a region and then check whether your touch point is inside a path, how it is [described there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588003/android-how-to-check-if-a-path-contains-touched-point).