# How can I determine whether a Point is within a Path(wpf)?

Tags: wpf, path, shapes

In a `Wpf` Project, I have a path and i want to know that is the path contains this point ? how i can determine it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044838/finding-points-contained-in-a-path-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Geometry.FillContains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615660(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
bool inside = path.Data.FillContains(point);
```