# Howto find out if an empty, transparent view was touched in android?

Tags: android, touch

I have a ViewGroup which fills a part of it's size, see the picture.
Further this ViewGroup implements onTouchListener.

Is there an easy way to find out, whether a transparent or the filled part was touched?
Something like: `ViewGroup.hasSomePixels(relativeX,relativeY)` ?

[image: see this image]

Comment: I'm looking for a method, if there will be any pixels, when the view will be drawn on point x,y , if possible without previeous knowledge how the view will look like.
Just looking in which half the click occured wont work with complicated shapes.

Comment: For the future I will avoid this situation by wrapping every object in an own `View`, so that android can forward touch events automatically to the top visible `View`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was working with Paths - for me it was the solution to surround the green area by a path and to check, whether the given point x,y is contained within the path.

Since paths do not support the contains(x,y) method, I used a workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597590/how-can-i-tell-if-a-closed-path-contains-a-given-point)

Answer (score 2):

If you implement the onTouch method you will see that you get a MotionEvent, when the view is touched.

```
onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {...}
```

the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) gives you information about the touch position. You can get the raw pixel coordinates on the screen with

```
event.getRawX();
event.getRawY();
```

or the coordinates relative to the view with

```
event.getX();
event.getY();
```

take a look at the [MotionEvent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) to learn more about it.

After that you can get the drawing cache and get the pixel value of the position.

```
this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());
this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

Then you have to check if the color is transparent or not.

Comment: I dont need the coordinates, I want to know whether the coordinates on this canvas's view will be filled or not, when onDraw will be called.

Answer (score 2):

I presume the image is a bitmap or a picture right? Then you can just do:

```
ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

and then decode the colour using `Color.red(pixel)` etc.. Admittedly, you'll need to keep track of any offsets (if the image is too large for the screen and can be dragged etc, but it's possible.

If you're dealing with a `Canvas` object, remember it just writes it all to a bitmap, so you can still do the above method (once you've accounted for offsets).

Comment: The picture is drawn on the canvas dynamically, by using paths and filling them. Have many different Paths, no chance to check 1 Object. They come together on the canvas, `onDraw`

Answer (score 0):

You can get point that was touched by calling: `event.getX()` and e`vent.getY()`. You can get dimensions of the screen by calling:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

You could do something like:

```
if (event.getY() <= height / 2) {
     //upper part of the screen: green was touched
} else {
     //white was touched
}
```

Comment: I would like to know if there are pixels in the coordinates x,y without the knowledge how the filled part looks like. Because i have much more complicated, dynamic shapes, so just looking which shape was touched wont work.