# How to know if a point is inside of a polygon in android

Tags: java, android, graphics

Given a succession of points describing a polygon, is there some easy way of know if a given point is inside the polygon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597590/how-can-i-tell-if-a-closed-path-contains-a-given-point

Comment: possible duplicate of [Point in Polygon aka hit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement one famous algorithm http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0103/algorithm_0103.htm