# finding if the click exists in set of coordinates

Tags: java, android

Suppose i have coordinates of a rectangle. Now i want to find out if the touch event or click event position exists within the rectangle, How can i do that?

```
A      B

    C

D      E
```

E.g i have this rectangle `ABDE`. I clicked on C, now i have all the coordinates. How can i figure out that c exists within `ABDE`

I assume that `Martix` is created for this purpose but I can't find any particular examples on internet.

Best Regards

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597590/how-can-i-tell-if-a-closed-path-contains-a-given-point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the points you have given in your example with the corresponding coordinates:

```
A(x1, y1)      B(x2, y1)

    C(x, y)

D(x1, y2)      E(x2, y2)
```

Point C is within the rectangle only and only if:

```
if(((x >= x1) && (x <= x2)) && ((y >= y1) && (y <= y2)){
   System.println.out("Point C is within the rectangle");
}
```

Comment: can you tell where can i store these coordinates, right now i am using float[] x .. x[0] for x and x[1] for y etc

Comment: @user966227 Yes that can do it. You can express every point in a float[2] where float[0] is x and float[1] is y

Answer (score 0):

Express your rectangle as smallest (X;Y) (`min(A.X,B.X...);min(A.Y...)`) and biggest (X;Y), then check that `c.X >= min.X && c.X <= max.X && c.Y >= min.Y && c.Y <= max.Y`.

Comment: Or he can use region.contains that do exactly the same thing.

Comment: actually its a textView and i am getting its coordinates